# Limit the onEdite(e) function

Tags: triggers

I am quite new to google sheets and scripts.
I am trying to create a table for different users to add a row and fill certain cells on their phones.

My Problem:

- The buttons on the sheet do not work on Android
- the onOpen(e) function does not pass on Android
- I don't know how to limit the onEdit(e) to a dropdown in cell(1,1) and not any other actions after that.

Any easy and understandable solution?
Thanks in advance,
Amir

Comment: There is so much general information in this question.

Comment: Hi Ahmad,Here is the code:function onEdit(e) {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  //var BeforeLastRow = lastRow-1;
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var driverName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
           sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);// Adds a row

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();   
           sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(currentDate);
           sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(driverName);
           sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,3).setValue(currentDate);
    }

Comment: Hi Ahmad, I need to know how to pass the onOpen(e) function to others especially on their Android phone. Or how to limit OnEdit(e) or onSelectionRange(e) to a specific cell to trigger the code. I do not want to trigger the code when the user changes a cell etc.